# R Conditional IfElse With Random Values

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table

```
data1 = data.frame("Cat" = c(8,4,3,7),
                   "Dog"=c(4,7,10,5),
                   "Want"=NA)

data1$Try = ifelse(data1$Dog > data1$Cat, (data1$Dog - data1$Cat) * (1-runif(1, 0.5, 0.9)), -99)
```

I wish to create "Want" with this rule:
  if Dog > Cat,
"Want" = (Dog - Cat) * (1-runif(1, 0.5, 0.9))

However when I do this with "Try" it uses the same random 'runif' value, however, for each time Dog > Cat I wish to generate a new value from 'runif' and not use the same one each time.

```
data1 = data.frame("Cat" = c(8,4,3,7),
                   "Dog"=c(4,7,10,5),
                   "Want"=NA)

data1 <- within(data1, Want2 <- ifelse(Dog-Cat>0,(Dog-Cat)*(1-runif(1, 0.5, 0.9)),-99))
data1$Dif = (data1$Dog - data1$Cat)/data1$Want2
```

I wish for this ratio to be different each time Dog > Cat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by `sample`ing:

```
data1$Want = ifelse(data1$Dog > data1$Cat, 
                (data1$Dog - data1$Cat) * (1-runif(sample(1:10,1, replace = T), 0.5, 0.9)), -99)
```

Comment: yes but i want the values to be different each time Dog > Cat in the same iteration as mentioned. Please see new comment on post, and thank you so much @Chris Ruehlemann

Comment: Does it make a difference if you put `sample`**behind** `runif`, thus: `data1$Want3 = ifelse(data1$Dog > data1$Cat, 
                    (data1$Dog - data1$Cat) * (1 - runif(sample(1:10,1, replace = T), 0.5, 0.9)), -99)`?

Comment: Okay, I'm glad it helped. I'll update my answer accordingly. Do feel free to accept it by clicking the green tick!

Answer (score 1):

You can try `ifelse` like below

```
data1 <- within(data1, Want <- ifelse(Dog-Cat>0,(Dog-Cat)*(1-runif(nrow(data1), 0.5, 0.9)),-99))
```

Comment: thank you but it still uses the same value @ThomasIsCoding

Comment: @bvowe Thanks for feedback! I updated my solution, where `runif(nrow(data1), 0.5, 0.9)` is used instead of `runif(1, 0.5, 0.9)` within `ifelse`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
data1 %>% 
   mutate(Want = case_when(Dog > Cat ~ (Dog - Cat)* 
      (1 - runif(sample(1:10,1, replace = T), 0.5, 0.9)), TRUE ~ -99))
```